# How to format text differently when longer than a specific length?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an API-log where every transaction is shown in a table-fashion (10 per page) and am using PrettyPrint to make the content inside the transacitons...well...prettier...

The problem is that some of the content is about 32 000 words and takes so long to prettify that it gives a timeout.

An example would be:

```
<strong>ResponseContent:</strong><br /> <pre class="prettyprint lang-java">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resCont) </pre><br /><br />
```

What I want to do is to use only:

```
<strong>ResponseContent:</strong><br /> <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resCont) </pre><br /><br />
```

When there is more than say... 5000 words.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: maybe you can just use back-end to render it? if `brabra.length` > 5000 then display your below code

Comment: @twxia Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Really don't know your back-end language and template engine. I think process this situation in back-end is 
more appropriate. you can add your back-end detail here and add the tags

Comment: It's built in C#, MVC. And I will look into it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<strong>ResponseContent:</strong><br />
@if (resCont.Length > 5000)
{
    <pre>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resCont) </pre>
}
else
{
    <pre class="prettyprint lang-java">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => resCont) </pre>
}
<br /><br />
```